# After reboot system time changed and menu bar items changed position

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, menu-bar, timezone

I'm new to Apple Mac OS, just Bought a new Macbook pro 13" Mid 2012 a month ago. Yesterday everything was good and working fine. I shut down system and went to sleep. Today when I Started my system I found some significant changes.

My system time went wrong from AM/PM to 24 hours which I fixed from apple Date/Time preferences. The but it just worked for the Menu Bar Display. System time is still 24hour format I can see in Terminal and start up Login Screen. In the Menu bar it is now showing the day number of the Week not the name as it was doing previously.

2nd is that in meny Bar the time is now shifted to left of Battery which was by default to right most and right to battery:

[image]

What is wrong with my system. I installed Macports yesterday. Don't know what else has been changed :(.

Comment: @patrix thanks for editing my post. 50% Solved. I went to Date/Time Preferences and Clicked on **Open Language & Text....** and then I resettled the values to my locale. The only issue left is to re-order the the menu bar let Date/Time to its original position to right most of to the right of battery icon. Can some Apple guru help me for this?

Comment: I was too hurry to tell. My system time is still in 24 hour format on Terminal and all other places except the menu bar Date/Time Display. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu bar icons can be repositioned by dragging them left and right with the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> pressed.

Comment: Awesome it worked for me. But the other issue is still there. My Boot Login Screen Time is 24 format. And the Menu bar Let Time is 12 hour format. I want all 12 format. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It worked again magic of an Apple Update. I just updated and I'm back to Original states of everything. thanks Patrix for your help.